# Is the norm on this site that posters should complete the elisp tutorial before asking questions?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

As suggested in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/45400/20570). If so, it would be useful to have that guidance on the ask page, as it's a much stronger norm than most SE sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is definitely not the norm that you should complete the Elisp tutorial before posting.

You certainly don't need to read the Elisp tutorial if all you want to do is tweak Emacs a little. It would be a good idea to do it if you want to write more advanced cutomizations, but even then you don't *have* to.

---

That “answer” did not answer the question and has now been deleted.